# Can't get PostGIS to show points on map - no button to activate map?

Tags: postgis, geometry

PostgreSQL 12 and PostGIS 3.0.1 on Windows 10, using PGAdmin4. I'm totally new to PGAdmin4 having recently come from PostgreSQL 9 / PGAdmin III - frankly, I don't like it but I'm trying.

For the first time, I'm attempting to use PostGIS to calculate point-to-point distance from a list of a few hundred points (eventually up to 1500). I see there is a feature to allow a visual map of the points based on their location, but the functionality isn't showing on my installation - the Mapping icon (blue, I think) isn't there on the column display as I've seen on the 'net.

I've gone thorough everything I can find and I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong. I've verified PostGIS is enabled and re-created the column in a couple different ways with no change. I re-set the geometry field because I learned that longitude comes first in Postgis (odd in my view, but I'm sure there's a reason) but that didn't help either. I learned that using "4326" SRID is required so I've done that in a couple different ways also. My database/schema has the required "spatial_ref_sys" table in it. I don't know what else to check.

`select * from pg_extension` gives me;

```
  oid  |  extname  |  extowner  |  extnamespace  |  extrelocatable  |  extversion  |  extconfig  |  extcondition
"13304"  "plpgsql"      "10"           "11"             false             "1.0"         [null]         [null]
"19086"  "postgis"      "10"        "16460"             true            "3.0.1"        "{19391}"   "{"WHERE NOT (
"20595" "adminpack"     "10"           "11"             false             "2.0"         [null]         [null]
```

The "WHERE NOT (" part followed by 500+ lines listing all the SRID codes.

This command I found on the web does not work at all:

`SELECT AddGeometryColumn('example', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2)`

and results in:

```
ERROR:  function public.addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, integer, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT public.AddGeometryColumn('','',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5, $6)
```

I can't seem to get it to point to my schema no matter what I do. So I used these commands to add my column and update the geometry field (lon_dec and lat_dec contain long/lat in decimal degrees):

`ALTER TABLE kmsy.ground_points ADD COLUMN geom kmsy.geometry(Point,4326)`

`UPDATE ground_points SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon_dec, lat_dec), 4326)`

but the SRID constraint is not appearing in the table list.I know I've done something basic wrong, I just can't find it.

Comment: How does the latitude/longitude data look like?

Comment: I tried a couple ways, but mainly converted it from Deg./min/sec to decimal degrees using postgres and stored it as double precision, so the fields look like: long = -90.27929551184526, lat = 29.99656421475608. Then used SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-90.27929551184526, 29.99656421475608),4326) to make the geom field.

Comment: . I can do ST_Distance with it, but not getting mapping. I think I must not have all the needed extensions enabled.